# Unable to parse response xml properly

Tags: jquery, xml, xpath

I am getting a response xml when i invoke a rest service in my html page.
Response xml looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<sys:systems xmlns:sys="http://tempuri.org">
    <system>
        <ID>System1</ID>
        <ScheduledStartDateTime>2013-06-12T00:00:00</ScheduledStartDateTime>
        <ScheduledEndDateTime></ScheduledEndDateTime>
        <operations>
            <operation>
                <OperationID>0010</OperationID>
                <Status>Running</Status>
                <ID>10003814</ID>
            </operation>
        </operations>
    </system>
</sys:systems>
```

Then i am trying to parse the above response using jQuery and for that i am doing something like :

```
$(xmlDoc).find('sys\\:systems\\system\\ID,ID').text();
```

Upon doing alert of above statement i get the ID Value but i get both the ID value instead of getting only one ID value.

**So what i am trying to fetch is ID=System1 but i am getting both System1 as well as 10003814.**

How can i get only System1 as ID? Looking forward to your solutions.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target the `ID` node you want directly using the descendant selector. Try this:

```
var id = $(xmlDoc).find('system > ID').text();
```

Working example:

```js
var xmlDoc = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><sys:systems xmlns:sys="http://tempuri.org"><system><ID>System1</ID><ScheduledStartDateTime>2013-06-12T00:00:00</ScheduledStartDateTime><ScheduledEndDateTime></ScheduledEndDateTime><operations><operation><OperationID>0010</OperationID><Status>Running</Status><ID>10003814</ID></operation></operations></system></sys:systems>'

var id = $(xmlDoc).find('system > ID').text();
alert(id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i just wanted to ask one more thing. How can i get the second ID using similar above expression?

Comment: `$('system OD').last()` or `$('system > operations > operation > ID')`. Note that you may need a loop if you have multiple `system` or `operation` nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you iterate through each `<system>` when there are multiple `<system>`

```
$(xml).find("system").each(function(){
        var unitData=$(this).find("ID:first").text()
        alert(unitData);
});
```

```js
var xml='<sys:systems xmlns:sys="http://tempuri.org"><system><ID>System1</ID><ScheduledStartDateTime>2013-06-12T00:00:00</ScheduledStartDateTime><ScheduledEndDateTime></ScheduledEndDateTime><operations><operation><OperationID>0010</OperationID><Status>Running</Status><ID>10003814</ID></operation></operations></system><system><ID>System1</ID><ScheduledStartDateTime>2013-06-12T00:00:00</ScheduledStartDateTime><ScheduledEndDateTime></ScheduledEndDateTime><operations><operation><OperationID>0010</OperationID><Status>Running</Status><ID>10003814</ID></operation></operations></system></sys:systems>';

$(xml).find("system").each(function(){
        var unitData=$(this).find("ID:first").text()
        alert(unitData);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/gfc6Lx41/1/)**

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)